# Wall Bump nodes wrong colour

Tags: bump

I want to give some detail to a wall old plaster holes etc. I added a image texture for the wallpaper added the bump nodes etc but the bump areas are the same colour as the image texture wallpaper, Q: I would like the bumps to be a different col how can I do this? cheers

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't have your file so I had to try to replicate it with brick texture and you can actually do it like this:
[image]

Is this what you wanted? If it is not perfect you can try something different than Mix or change some values

You can also use another colorRamp to further control colors

Comment: Thx Miko I will give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work